# Record types for junction object

Tags: junction-object

I need a junction object to link my account to the custom object offer and promotion. Since both of the custom objects are related to pricing, I was wondering if I can create a pricing package junction object, and depending on the record type selected, the user can link to either offer or promotion. Would that make sense? Tia.

Answer (score 0):

This would not work because you can only have up to two master-detail relationships on an object. You cannot have three (one to Account, one to Offer and one to Promotion).

You could have two lookup relationships to Offer and Promotion instead, but the result would no longer be a junction object. Maybe this works for your requirements or maybe you have to create two junction objects.